# I need to find out x-path for only number of videos present in page using selenium

Tags: selenium

I need to find out x-path for only number of videos present in page using selenium.

```
<div>
  <h4>
    From 
    <a href="/publishers/957-buzzfeed">BuzzFeed </a>
    •  2188 Videos
</h4>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the text containg number of videos as follows:
String headerText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > h4")).getText();

Then, replace all the non-digiy charecters from headerText like this:

int totalVideos = Integer.valueOf(headerText.replaceAll("\\D+"));

Comment: I'm using like this but not getting 2188 values only:String headerText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div > h4")).getText();
  int totalVideos = Integer.valueOf(headerText.replaceAll("//D+//D+//D",headerText));

Comment: i want only 2188 value

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped earlier. Now check the edited answer.

Comment: it would be great if i know the path for only 2188 value